# what architecture to use with asp.net mvc vd web forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

please explain how to get high capacity architectures with both the default asp.net web forms and mvc models with regard to being able to serve millions of page views.

i want to know how to set up each model from DB clustering, to caching, logical/ physical tiers, load balancing iis servers, scaling out or up, session state management and so on...

is one more scalable than the other?

thanks all.

Comment: Short answer: nope, none is intrinsically more scalable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035642/asp-net-mvc-vs-webforms-speed-and-architecture-comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one answer.  A good option is to check the architectures for some respected Open source projects to see what other people are doing.

Comment: can you have mvc on the same architecture as webforms? that is to say with iis nodes, maybe a separate server for business objects and DB servers?